# Adding Google Calendar item WITHOUT Zend Framework

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

For some reason, both SO and Google searches on "Google Calendar add item without zend", gives me blogs and examples where they use Zend Framework.

I cannot use Zend Framework. So, i'm looking for a snippet/script that let me add a new item in the Google Calendar with PHP, without Zend Framework. I do not require any credentials since the system posts it as the "owner" of the calendar.

Can somebody, PLEASE help me out here? The Google API PHP Client Example only allows me to call the Calendar and shows me the current items. I don't want to read, i want to insert.

Comment: "google calendar" -"zend framework"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me, there's no other (good, working) solution. So, I used Zend Framework :(

Comment: @ceejayoz, it took me a couple of hours to rewrite loaders and other stuff, to make it work..